# How to make this cube a Sphere in P5.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, p5.js

I've been developing a procedural cube, which is built in three steps.

1. Setting up the vectors
2. Drawing the triangles needed
3. Normalizing to convert to sphere

My problem regards to the last step, when I normalize the vectors it only shows a quarter of a sphere. Could anyone help me out with this?

```
let world;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500, WEBGL);
    
    world = new cube(9, 80); // Testing values
  
}
  
    function draw() {

        background(200);
        world.createVertices();
        //world.drawPoints();
        world.createTriangles();
        world.drawTriangles();


    }   

class cube {
 
    constructor(resolution,scale,vertices, triangles, roundness, normals) {

        this.resolution = resolution;
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.triangles = triangles;
        this.normals = normals;
    }

    createVertices() {
        let cornerVertices = 8;
        let edgeVertices = ((this.resolution * 3) - 3) * 4;
        let faceVertices = ((this.resolution - 1) * (this.resolution - 1) +(this.resolution - 1) * (this.resolution - 1) +(this.resolution- 1) * (this.resolution - 1)) * 2;
        let totalVertices = cornerVertices + edgeVertices + faceVertices // For checking purposes only
        this.vertices = []
        this.normals = []
        let v = 0;

        for (let y = 0; y <= this.resolution; y++) {
            for (let x = 0; x <= this.resolution; x++) {
                this.SetVertex(v++, x, y, 0);
            }
            for (let z = 1; z <= this.resolution; z++) {
                this.SetVertex(v++, this.resolution, y, z);                     
            }
            for (let x = this.resolution - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                this.SetVertex(v++, x, y, this.resolution)
                
            }
            for (let z = this.resolution - 1; z > 0; z--) {
                this.SetVertex(v++, 0, y, z);
            }
        }
        for (let z = 1; z < this.resolution; z++) {
            for (let x = 1; x < this.resolution; x++) {
                this.SetVertex(v++, x, this.resolution, z);
            }
        }

        for (let z = 1; z < this.resolution; z++) {
            for (let x = 1; x < this.resolution; x++) {
                this.SetVertex(v++, x, 0, z);
            }
        }

        console.log(this.vertices)
        console.log(totalVertices)
    }

    createTriangles() {

        let quads = (this.resolution * this.resolution + this.resolution * this.resolution + this.resolution * this.resolution) * 2; // For checking purposes only
        this.triangles = [];
        let ring = (this.resolution * 2) * 2;
        let t = 0
        let v = 0;

        for (let y = 0; y < this.resolution; y++, v++) {
            for (let q = 0; q < ring - 1; q++, v++) {
                t = this.SetQuad(this.triangles, t, v, v + 1, v + ring, v + ring + 1);
            }
            t = this.SetQuad(this.triangles, t, v, v - ring + 1, v + ring, v + 1);
        }

        t = this.CreateTopFace(this.triangles, t, ring);
        t = this.CreateBottomFace(t, ring);

        console.log(this.triangles)

    }

    drawPoints() {
        strokeWeight(1);
        let angleX = 200
        let angleY = 500
        let angleZ = 100
        beginShape(POINTS);
        for(let i = 0; i < this.vertices.length; i++) {
            vertex(this.vertices[i].x  * this.scale,this.vertices[i].y * -this.scale,this.vertices[i].z * this.scale)
            rotateX(angleX)
            rotateY(angleY)
            rotateZ(angleZ)
        }
        endShape();
    }

    drawTriangles(){

        let coordinates = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.triangles.length; i++){
          coordinates.push(this.vertices[this.triangles[i]])
        }

        console.log(coordinates)


        for(let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i =  i + 3) {
            beginShape(TRIANGLES);
            vertex(coordinates[i].x  * this.scale,coordinates[i].y * -this.scale,coordinates[i].z * this.scale)
            vertex(coordinates[i + 1].x  * this.scale,coordinates[i + 1].y * -this.scale,coordinates[i + 1].z * this.scale)
            vertex(coordinates[i + 2].x  * this.scale,coordinates[i + 2].y * -this.scale,coordinates[i + 2].z * this.scale) 
            endShape();
        }
       

    }

// Define vertex order.
    SetQuad (triangles,  i,  v00,  v10,  v01,  v11) {
        triangles[i] = v00;
        triangles[i + 1] = triangles[i + 4] = v01;
        triangles[i + 2] = triangles[i + 3] = v10;
        triangles[i + 5] = v11;
        return i + 6;
    }

    CreateTopFace(triangles,t, ring) {
        let v = ring * this.resolution;
        for (let x = 0; x < this.resolution - 1; x++, v++) {
            t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, v, v + 1, v + ring - 1, v + ring);
        }
        t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, v, v + 1, v + ring - 1, v + 2);

        let vMin = ring * (this.resolution + 1) - 1;
        let vMid = vMin + 1;
        let vMax = v + 2;

        for (let z = 1; z < this.resolution - 1; z++, vMin--, vMid++, vMax++) {
            t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMin, vMid, vMin - 1, vMid + this.resolution- 1);
            for (let x = 1; x < this.resolution - 1; x++, vMid++) {
                t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMid, vMid + 1, vMid + this.resolution - 1, vMid + this.resolution);
            }
            t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMid, vMax, vMid + this.resolution - 1, vMax + 1);
        }

        let vTop = vMin - 2;
        t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMin, vMid, vTop + 1, vTop);
        for (let x = 1; x < this.resolution - 1; x++, vTop--, vMid++) {
            t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMid, vMid + 1, vTop, vTop - 1);
        }
        t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMid, vTop - 2, vTop, vTop - 1);

        return t;
    }

    CreateBottomFace (triangles, t, ring) {
        let v = 1;
        let vMid = this.vertices.length - (this.resolution - 1) * (this.resolution - 1);
        t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, ring - 1, vMid, 0, 1);
        for (let x = 1; x < this.resolution - 1; x++, v++, vMid++) {
            t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMid, vMid + 1, v, v + 1);
        }
        t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMid, v + 2, v, v + 1);

        let vMin = ring - 2;
        vMid -= this.resolution - 2;
        let vMax = v + 2;

        for (let z = 1; z < this.resolution - 1; z++, vMin--, vMid++, vMax++) {
            t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMin, vMid + this.resolution - 1, vMin + 1, vMid);
            for (let x = 1; x < this.resolution - 1; x++, vMid++) {
                t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t,vMid + this.resolution - 1, vMid + this.resolution, vMid, vMid + 1);
            }
            t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vMid + this.resolution - 1, vMax + 1, vMid, vMax);
        }

        let vTop = vMin - 1;
        t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vTop + 1, vTop, vTop + 2, vMid);
        for (let x = 1; x < this.resolution - 1; x++, vTop--, vMid++) {
            t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vTop, vTop - 1, vMid, vMid + 1);
        }
        t = this.SetQuad(triangles, t, vTop, vTop - 1, vMid, vTop - 2);

        return t;
    }

    SetVertex (i, x, y, z) {
        let v = createVector(x, y, z)
        v = v.mult(2) 
        v = v.div(this.resolution - 1)
        
        this.normals[i] = v.normalize();
        this.vertices[i] = this.normals[i];
    }


    

}
```